# Paramiko output is inconsistent?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Paramiko is giving me different output with each run, just curious why that is. Sometimes it returns this:

```
The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
...

$ 
$ su -
Password:
```

And other times it returns this:

```
The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
...

$ $ su -
Password:
```

This is my code:

```
def execute_shell_command(self, command, timeout=10, wait_for_answer=True):
    if self.session is None:
        message = "'{}' could not execute '{}', session is not open".format(self.interface_id, command)
        self.sys_conf.logger.warning(message)
        raise SessionIsNotAvailable(message)

    channel = self.shell
    channel.set_combine_stderr(True)
    output_lines = []
    try:
        # Clear the buffer before executing any commands
        while channel.recv_ready():
            output_lines.append(channel.recv(99999).decode("utf-8", "ignore"))

        # Execute command, wait {timeout} seconds and try to clear the buffer again.
        channel.send('{}\n'.format(command))
        time.sleep(timeout)
        if wait_for_answer:
            while channel.recv_ready():
                output_lines.append(channel.recv(99999).decode("utf-8", "ignore"))

    except socket.timeout as e:
        message = "Timeout reached - failed to execute command '{}'".format(command)
        self.sys_conf.logger.warning(message)
        raise ExecutionTimeout(message, e)

    answer = "".join(output_lines)
    if wait_for_answer:
        return answer
```

Just seems strange to me, there shouldn't be any difference since it's the same commands to the same server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because of this:

```
channel.set_combine_stderr(True)
```

You are telling Paramiko to combine stdout and stderr into one stream.  But how that's done may depend on timing.

You might try not combining the streams, and seeing what happens then.

Comment: Followup question: What affects timing?

Comment: @AlexOsheter: Who knows.  It's non-deterministic as you've discovered.  Maybe the machine is more or less busy at some particular moment.